# Share Prisma Types Between Microservices

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, microservices, prisma

I'm working on a project right now that has multiple TypeScript microservices performing operations on the same database. In each microservice, we are using the Prisma client to perform database operations. The issue I'm experiencing is we need to duplicate our `schema.prisma` file in each microservice and generate the Prisma client for each service. Is there a way to manage our database in a separate project while sharing the generated client between the microservices **without** having duplicate `schema.prisma` in each project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

prisma generates a client from the schema. This client is as far as im aware totally independent of the schema files and the prisma package. If you copy those generated files in any way, you can reuse the client in a different project.

There is a nice article on medium using npm packages I guess.
https://isidoro-ferreiro.medium.com/share-your-prisma-client-across-projects-44d1c7aca6fd

However u could also use something like nodemon or your ci pipeline to copy the generated client files to the other services.

Comment: That article provided is not quite sufficient. We followed exact steps and when the library is imported, the construction of the LucaClient (for use within the suggested ctx) immediately throws an error because its not looking in the library for the schema. Its looking for it at Runtime from the Runtime current directory. Seeing as how both the client AND schema are generated, it should not be necessary to LOAD the schema file at all, and  certainly not from some arbitrary runtime directory. The design did not consider sharing `PrismaClient` across deployables as a "first class citizen"

Comment: Hi, did you find any workaround ? I am facing the same issue with prisma.

Comment: @Decoded any luck with a solution for sharing PrismaClient and Prisma?

Comment: @Decoded also looking for a solution, spent the last 48 hours trying to create a private NPM package. Why is this so hard? It should be a common task most people are trying to do...

Comment: @Leafyshark I've updated the answer to reflect our solution. It works well, and we don't have to remember to do the copying manually

Answer (score 0):

## Updated Answer from the Author

The way we handled it is using the `assets` block, which enables copying generated assets into every micro service which wants to share the schema  in the project.json which needs the dependency. This is a MonoRepo of course -  e.g.

````
"assets": [
  {
    "input": "libs/prisma/luca/",
    "output": "otherlocation/schema.prisma",
    "glob": "**/schema.prisma",
    "ignore": []
  },
]```
````

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I'm sorry this is hard to understand for me.